# How to implement Flutter Localization with Provider?

Tags: android, flutter

I wanted to make my application to work in 2 different language.
I guess problem is that I cannot handle *Cosumer* in multiprovider ,could it be?

I am using flutter_localization package alongside with flutter provider package;

Here is my code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  AppLanguage appLanguage = AppLanguage();
  await appLanguage.fetchLocale();
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    var darkModeOn = prefs.getBool('darkMode') ?? true;
    runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeManager>(
        builder: (_) => ThemeManager(lightTheme),
        child: MyApp(appLanguage: appLanguage),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

Class My App

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final AppLanguage appLanguage;

  MyApp({this.appLanguage});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeManager>(context);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ApiService()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ApiService, StudentData>(
          builder: (ctx, auth, _) => StudentData(auth.token, auth.school),
        )
      ],
      child: Consumer<ApiService>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => ChangeNotifierProvider<AppLanguage>(
          builder: (_) => appLanguage,
          child: Consumer<AppLanguage>(
            builder: (context, model, child) => MaterialApp(
              locale: appLanguage.appLocal,
              supportedLocales: [Locale('ru', 'RU'), Locale('uz', 'UZ')],
              localizationsDelegates: [
                AppLocalization.delegate,
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: "Socratus |Mobile",
              theme: themeNotifier.getTheme(),
              home: auth.isAuth
                  ? MainScreen()
                  : FutureBuilder(
                      future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
                      builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) => LoginScreen()),
              routes: {
                MainScreen.routeName: (ctx) => MainScreen(),
                ProfilePage.routeName: (ctx) => ProfilePage(),
                SettingsPage.routeName: (ctx) => SettingsPage(
                      appLanguage: appLanguage,
                    ),
                ChangePassword.routeName: (ctx) => ChangePassword(),
                HomeworkScreen.routeName: (ctx) => HomeworkScreen(),
                HWDetails.routeName: (ctx) => HWDetails(),
                NewsPage.routeName: (ctx) => NewsPage(),
                QuestionAndAnswers.routeName: (ctx) => QuestionAndAnswers(),
                MyDownloads.routeName: (ctx) => MyDownloads(),
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here how I tried to implement

```
class AppLocalization {
  final Locale locale;

  AppLocalization(this.locale);

  static AppLocalization of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalization>(context, AppLocalization);
  }

  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalization> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationDelegate();

  Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    String jsonString = await rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/translations/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

    _localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });

    return true;
  }

  String translate(String key) {
    return _localizedStrings[key];
  }
}

class _AppLocalizationDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalization> {
  // This delegate instance will never change (it doesn't even have fields!)
  // It can provide a constant constructor.
  const _AppLocalizationDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    // Include all of your supported language codes here
    return ['ru', 'uz'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalization> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalization localizations = new AppLocalization(locale);
    await localizations.load();
    return localizations;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_AppLocalizationDelegate old) => false;
}
```

And my provider :

```
class AppLanguage extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _appLocale = Locale('ru');

  Locale get appLocal => _appLocale ?? Locale("ru");
  fetchLocale() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getString('language_code') == null) {
      _appLocale = Locale('ru');
      return Null;
    }
    _appLocale = Locale(prefs.getString('language_code'));
    return Null;
  }

  void changeLanguage(Locale type) async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (_appLocale == type) {
      return;
    }
    if (type == Locale("uz")) {
      _appLocale = Locale("uz");
      await prefs.setString('language_code', 'uz');
      await prefs.setString('countryCode', 'UZ');
    } else {
      _appLocale = Locale("ru");
      await prefs.setString('language_code', 'ru');
      await prefs.setString('countryCode', 'RU');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

If this is not a correct way , how can I implement this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to implement is explained in [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2), if you'd like a different approach I'd suggest you to check out [Easy Localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) from pub.dev which is currently handling well all the [Flutter internationalization features](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization).

Answer (score 0):

**MY SOLUTION**

Note:

- Used [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) for persistent key/value storage.
- The above question has been asked in reference to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@sofya.noskova/flutter-localization-with-provider-d9400bb05c05)

**`main.dart`**

```
void main() async {
  ...
  ///Initialize Storage
  await GetStorage.init();
  ...
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    ///Check for locale
    AppLanguage language = AppLanguage();
    language.fetchLocale();

    final providers = [
       /**
       * Add all providers in here like below
       *  ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeModel>(create: (context) => ThemeModel(),),
       */
      ...
      ///Language provider
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AppLanguage>(
        create: (context) => language,
      ),
      ...
     
    ];

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: providers,
      child: Consumer<AppLanguage>(
        builder: (context, model, _) {
          /**
           * Access other providers apart from language like below
           * Provider.of<ThemeModel>(context).theme,
           */
          ...
          return MaterialApp(
            locale: model.appLocal,
           supportedLocales: [
             Locale('ru', 'RU'), 
             Locale('uz', 'UZ'),
             ],
            localizationsDelegates: [
              AppLocalization.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            ...
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the provider **`language.dart`**

```
class AppLanguage extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _appLocale = Locale('ru');

  Locale get appLocal => _appLocale;

  fetchLocale() async {
    var storage = GetStorage();
    if (!(storage.hasData('language_code'))) {
      _appLocale = Locale('ru');
      return Null;
    }

    _appLocale = Locale(storage.read('language_code'));
    return Null;
  }

  Future<void> updateLanguage(Locale type) async {
    var storage = GetStorage();
    if (_appLocale == type) {
      return;
    }

    if (type == Locale('uz')) {
      _appLocale = Locale('sw');
      await storage.write('language_code', 'uz');
      await storage.write('countryCode', 'UZ');
    } else {
      _appLocale = Locale('ru');
      await storage.write('language_code', 'ru');
      await storage.write('countryCode', 'RU');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The `AppLocalization` class on the above question has been implemented correctly.

**USAGE**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    final languageModel = Provider.of<LanguageModel>(context);
    ...
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  ...
                  onTap: () {
                    languageModel.appLocal == Locale('ru')
                        ? languageModel.updateLanguage(Locale('uz'))
                        : languageModel.updateLanguage(Locale('ru'));
                  },
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Thoughts**

- Language provider should be consumed first and the rest to follow i.e `ApiService`.. e.t.c.

Any misconception on my code and bugs, don't hesitate to comment. I will reply as soon as possible.